# Templates - incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

I have code like that:

```cpp
template<class T>
class A {
    T a;
};

template<class T>
class C {
    T c;
};

class B: protected A<C<B>> {

};

B b = B();
```

My intention is that the compiler should resolve that to (after substituting templates):

```cpp
class B: protected A {

};

class C {
    B c;
};

class A {
    C a;
};

B b = B();
```

However it doesn't compile (the code from the first snippet (with templates)). The error is:

"Field has incomplete type B" in the line "T c".

So I modify it like that:

```cpp
class B: protected A<C<B>> {

};

template<class T>
class A {
    T a;
};

template<class T>
class C {
    T c;
};
```

But then I had another problem. Generally, there is some problem with order of it, but I don't know how to declare it so that it compiles and doesn't throw "This type is incomplete" error or some other similar errors.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `B` to, ultimately, contain a member variable of type `B`. There's no way of rearranging declarations that will let you do that, because a member variable of type `B` would have to be as large as the entire containing class.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Your code cannot be made to compile without changing it substantially. How would you write the same without templates? Maybe that will make it easier to discuss your actual case

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 My second code snippet is how I would write this without templates.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it is, can you see a "template" keyword there?

Comment: oh right, sorry I missed that. Still not clear what you think you need it for. Its what Nathan wrote: `B` contains an `A` which contains an `C` which contains a `B`, so effectively every `B` contains another `B` and that `B` again contains another `B` ad infinitum. No real world thing can require you to use that.

Comment: ok, I will later update that with the real names instead of A, B, C to make it more clear how it's required.

Comment: same problem with `struct Foo { Foo foo;};` its not because c++ does not allow it, but because it is just not possible

Comment: make one of the members in the chain a pointer then it can work, because a pointer can be `nullptr`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You are right, I forgot about it. But I think that's another problem. There still will be a problem with templates.

Comment: no its actually the same problem. The templates and that the mutal members span across 3 types just make it a little harder to see it, otherwise it is exactly that problem

Comment: ok, you are right